# Allow InActive User selection via Flow Screen Input field - Lookup

Tags: visual-workflow, userlicense, lightning-flow-builder, deactivate

Can we display a field in Flow Screen to allow InActive user's search/selection along with Active user's ?

With existing screen input field "LookUp", it only allows searching/selection of Active User from the system.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't select inactive users in any standard interface, including flows and record edit pages. Inactive users effectively "do not exist" in Salesforce (e.g. they do not participate in sharing, records they own can't be edited without transferring to an active user, records can't be assigned to them, etc). You'll need to write some code for this, and even then, you'll be limited by system validations as to what you can do with that inactive user.

P.S. This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). In the future, I suggest including *context* in your question so that we can provide more detailed and helpful answers.

Comment: Agree with you on X-Y Problem, but I only wanted to explore very limited area to achieve this functionality hence formulated my question this way.

Anyway, today I found a workaround to this by populated a pick list with all users  (Active & InActive) via Record Choice Set.